# Unity UDP - Can't send and receive at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp

I've been trying to send coordinates of the players vector to the UDP server which is written in NodeJS. However, when I try to send the coordinates and receive them modified afterwards nothing shows. If I modify the server to send me info constantly, it works. Seems as if I can't send and receive at the same time.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


public class PlayerBehavior : MonoBehaviour {

    private UdpClient udpServer;
    public GameObject cube;
    private Vector3 tempPos;
    private Thread t;
    public float movementSpeed;
    private long lastSend;
    private IPEndPoint remoteEP;

    void Start()
    {
        udpServer = new UdpClient(41234);
        t = new Thread(() => {
            while (true) {
                this.receiveData();
            }
        });
        t.Start();
        t.IsBackground = true;
        remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("46.101.102.243"), 41234);
    }


    private long UnixTimeNow()
    {
        var timeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
        return (long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        udpServer.Close();
        t.Abort();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var isShift = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);
        if (isShift)
        {
            Debug.Log("Shift");
        }
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * this.movementSpeed;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * this.movementSpeed;
        cube.transform.Translate(x, 0, 0);
        cube.transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
        if (cube.transform.position != tempPos)
        {
            if (UnixTimeNow() - this.lastSend > 1000 / 24)
            {
                this.lastSend = UnixTimeNow();
                byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cube.transform.position.x + ";" + cube.transform.position.y + ";" + cube.transform.position.z);
                udpServer.Send(arr, arr.Length, remoteEP);
            }
        }
        tempPos = cube.transform.position;
    }

    private void receiveData() {
            Debug.Log("Trying to receive data...");
            byte[] data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP);
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                Debug.Log("Received Data" + str);
            }
    }

}
```

Would be thankful if anyone has some input or possible solutions. Searched almost everywhere but nothing seems to work accordingly.

**EDIT**
I've also tried with different UpdClients for the receive and send, aswell as IP endpoints. The issue still persists.

```
public class PlayerBehavior : MonoBehaviour {

    private UdpClient udpServer;
    private UdpClient udpServer2;
    public GameObject cube;
    private Vector3 tempPos;
    private Thread t;
    public float movementSpeed;
    private long lastSend;
    private IPEndPoint remoteEP;
    private IPEndPoint remoteEP2;

    void Start()
    {
        udpServer = new UdpClient();
        remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("46.101.102.243"), 41234);
        remoteEP2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("46.101.102.243"), 41234);
        udpServer.Connect(remoteEP);

        udpServer2 = new UdpClient();
        udpServer2.Connect(remoteEP2);

        t = new Thread(() => {
            while (true) {
                this.receiveData();
            }
        });
        t.Start();
        t.IsBackground = true;

    }


    private long UnixTimeNow()
    {
        var timeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
        return (long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        udpServer.Close();
        t.Abort();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var isShift = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift);
        if (isShift)
        {
            Debug.Log("Shift");
        }
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * this.movementSpeed;
        var z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * this.movementSpeed;
        cube.transform.Translate(x, 0, 0);
        cube.transform.Translate(0, 0, z);
        if (cube.transform.position != tempPos)
        {
            if (UnixTimeNow() - this.lastSend > 1000 / 24)
            {
                this.lastSend = UnixTimeNow();
                byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cube.transform.position.x + ";" + cube.transform.position.y + ";" + cube.transform.position.z);
                udpServer.Send(arr, arr.Length);
            }
        }
        tempPos = cube.transform.position;
    }

    private void receiveData() {
            Debug.Log("Trying to receive data...");
            byte[] data = udpServer2.Receive(ref remoteEP2);
            if (data.Length > 0)
            {
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                Debug.Log("Received Data: " + str);
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send and recieve at the same time, but do not use the same port for both directions

Comment: Would this be the port for the UdpClient or the IpEndPoints?

Comment: pick one point for recieve and another for sending, if you are sending to the local machine, only one program can listen on one port, so first program that opens the port for listening will block the other program from opening the port

Comment: Tried with both different endpoints and different updclients that it binds to. Issue still persists. I've attached the new code to the edit in the post.